# c++ [gamestate] function does not take in correct argument error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Hello i have problem of compile my code

i follow http://gamedevgeek.com/tutorials/managing-game-states-in-c/ tutorial
but it fail to compile and i don't know why.

the error msg from visual studio
[image]

here is my code

the CGameEngine modify code

```
    #include <vector>
    #include "GameState.h"
    #include "GameEngine.h"

    class GameState;

    class GameStateManager
    {
    public:
        GameStateManager(GameEngine* engine, MSG * msg);
        ~GameStateManager();

        void Cleanup();
        void ChangeState(GameState* state);
        void Update();
        bool Running() { return m_running; }
        void Quit();

    private:
        std::vector<GameState *> states;
        bool m_running;
        GameEngine * m_engine;
        MSG *m_msg;
    };

    #include "GameStateManager.h"


    GameStateManager::GameStateManager(GameEngine* engine, MSG * msg)
        :m_engine{ engine }, m_msg{ msg }, m_running{ true }
    {

    }

    GameStateManager::~GameStateManager()
    {

    }

    void GameStateManager::Cleanup()
    {
        while (!states.empty()) {
            states.back()->Exit();
            states.pop_back();
        }
    }

    void GameStateManager::Quit()
    {
        m_running = false;
        m_msg->message = WM_QUIT;
    }

    void GameStateManager::ChangeState(GameState* state)
    {
        if (!states.empty()) {
            states.back()->Exit();
            states.pop_back();
        }

        states.push_back(state);
        states.back()->Enter(m_engine, m_msg);
    }

    void GameStateManager::Update()
    {
        states.back()->Update(this);
    }
```

the CGameState modify code

```
    #include "GameStateManager.h"

    class GameState
    {
    public:
        GameState() {}
        virtual ~GameState() {}
        virtual void Enter(GameEngine * , MSG * ) = 0;
        virtual void Update(GameStateManager* game) =0;
        virtual void Exit() = 0;

    };
```

one of the state class

```
#include "MainMenu.h"

class Logo :public GameState
{
public:
    Logo();
    ~Logo();

    static Logo* Instance() 
    {
        return &m_Logo;
    }

    void Enter(GameEngine * engine, MSG * msg);
    void Update(GameStateManager* game);
    void Exit();
private:

    static Logo m_Logo;

};

#include "Logo.h"

Logo::Logo()
{

}

Logo::~Logo()
{

}
void Logo::Enter(GameEngine * engine, MSG * msg)
{
    m_GameEngine_Info = engine;
    m_msg = msg;

}

void Logo::Update(GameStateManager* game)
{


}

void Logo::Exit()
{


}
```

i get no compile error when editing the code, but when i try compile it get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have circular includes. Use include guards and replace

```
#include "GameStateManager.h"
```

with

```
class GameStateManager;
```

in GameState.h. Move this include into GameState.cpp.

Do similar with `#include "GameEngine.h"` and `#include "GameState.h"` in GameStateManager.h and GameStateManager.cpp.